# python; write dictionary and extra parameters to txt file

Tags: python

I have a script that makes a python dictionary by counting patterns in a file, and write the filename(basename) and headers before the counting results of the file (quiet large code, I assume that this does not matter for the question).

```
print(basename, header, counts)
```

The output of counts are the pattern and values.

My output looks like this:

```
filename1 header1 {'pattern1': 1, 'pattern2': 2}
filename1 header2 {'pattern3': 2, 'pattern4': 1}
filename2 header1 {'pattern5': 3, 'pattern6': 1}
```

I want to write the patterns and counts to a txt file, that includes the filename and header for each dictionary key and value, separated with a space, like this

```
    filename1 header1 pattern1 1
    filename1 header1 pattern2 2
    filename1 header2 pattern3 2 
    filename1 header2 pattern4 1
    filename2 header1 pattern5 3
    filename2 header1 pattern6 1
```

But I do not know how to achieve this. Can someone help me with the command to write the output like this?

Comment: Please try something and come back with a specific question. It is better to ask a separate specific question about every step of your own code than to just dump a bunch of requirements and get closed down.

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask].

Comment: Does order of `pattern1` and `pattern2` matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
for item in counts:
    print(basename, header, item, counts[item])
```

Also, You can do that in one line, but it's a little tricky ;)

```
print(basename, header, '\n%s %s '.join([(" ".join([str(lst),str(counts[lst])])) for lst in counts]) %(basename, header))
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop where you have `print(basename, pattern, counts)`, just add another loop over the dictionary.

```
for loop...: # not sure what it looks like
    for k, v in counts.items():
        print(basename, pattern, k, v)
```

`counts.items()` is `python3`, use `counts.iteritems()` for `python2`

Comment: true, though it returns a copy, which you probably don't want just for printing